# GLOP on N Nodes

Tags: c, teradata, user-defined-functions

I am unable to find any article related to working of GLOP when multiple nodes are accessing it. I have few questions if anyone can answer it or give me some link to it. I am learning on it. I have following questions.

- Are GLOPs a viable alternative to static memory?
- How is the read performance as opposed to accessing local RAM?
- How is GLOP data synchronized when:

  - a scalar udf runs on N nodes in parallel: select decrypt(email) from tableWithMillionsOfRows;
  - each of the N nodes does not find the needed data in the GLOP.
  - each of the N nodes retrieves an encryption key simultaneously
  - each of the N nodes writes the key to the GLOP.
  - is that a problem? Will these calls be somehow synchronized, or is it simply "last wins"?

Comment: What is GLOP?  Please provide a reference.

Comment: GLOP is ' Global and persistent memory'